# HTML Select Option tag having differemt colours on same row or same option

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a new requirement whereby we need to have a different colour for a single select list item i.e on a option row there needs to be 2 different colours.

Sample html code below:

```
<select name="test">
  <option value = "red blue"> red blue </option>
  <option style="color:blue;" value = "Row2"> Row2 </option>
  <option style="color:green;" value = "Row3"> Row3 </option>
</select>
```

For example for the first select option, I want to see text "red" in red colour and "blue" in blue colour in the same list item.

Please can someone provide a working example with complete code if possible

Many thanks

Comment: <select name="test">
<option value = "red blue"> red blue </option>
<option style="color:blue;" value = "Row2"> Row2 </option>
<option style="color:green;" value = "Row3"> Row3 </option>
</select>

Comment: It works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/f8vdnyn8/

Comment: So you mean to say you want to split the color values and apply for every term in the option??

Comment: Are you want to implement on dynamic list or static list? Please tell me. #Rthemus

Comment: Hi all thanks for getting back.it is a static list. All I want is as per my sample code the word red to show in red colour and the word blue to show in blue colour.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion and experimentation with your code, it might not be possible directly([failed code](https://jsfiddle.net/f8vdnyn8/7/)). But if you want a work around/fix for it, you can use a small external library like `purecss`(take the menu component of it) and simply write a code like this:

Just an example to give an idea.

HTML:

```
<div class="pure-menu pure-menu-horizontal">
  <ul class="pure-menu-list">
    <li class="pure-menu-item pure-menu-has-children pure-menu-allow-hover">
      <a href="#" id="menuLink1" class="pure-menu-link">select here</a>
      <ul class="pure-menu-children">
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link" value="red blue">red blue</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link" value="blue">Row2</a></li>
        <li class="pure-menu-item"><a href="#" class="pure-menu-link" value="green">Row3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".pure-menu-children li").each(function(i, opt){
  var colors = $(opt).find(".pure-menu-link").attr("value"); // get the value
  var txt = $(opt).find(".pure-menu-link").text(); // get the text
  var txtarr = txt.trim().split(" "); // split them
  var colorarr = colors.trim().split(" ");
  $(opt).find(".pure-menu-link").html(""); // clear the content of the option
  var len;
  if(txtarr.length >= colorarr.length){
    len = txtarr.length - colorarr.length;
    while(len--){
      colorarr.push("black");
    }
  }
  len = txtarr.length;
  while(len--){
    $(opt).find(".pure-menu-link").append("&nbsp;<span style='color : "+colorarr.shift()+"'>"+txtarr.shift()+"</span>&nbsp;");
  }  
});
```

Working code : https://jsfiddle.net/dkv6q2da/8/ (check the external sources for the menu component of purecss)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well I updated the code and answer, Now it should do the things its supposed to correctly, i guess

Comment: Thanks dvenkatsagar. Very helpful.

Comment: For I think you would need to add the html5shiv library, or something to make it modern enough. It not a problem with Jquery as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy you can just name the every option to a class and add the css style to that class as you like.
    
        This should have a WHITE background
        This should have a RED background
        This should have a YELLOW background
        This should have a GREEN background

```
<style type="text/css">
    .white {background:white;}
    .red {color:red;}
    .yellow {color:yellow;}
    .green {color:green}
</style> <!-- The styling you want can be given here -->
```

Comment: That is not what the OP wants, he wants to see each term in a option with a different color.

Comment: yes dvenkatsagar is right I want  different colours in the same row or within the same option tag. For example if the select option value is a sentence then the 1st word has to be in red and 2nd word in blue and 3rd word in green.  What the user wants is to break up the option value in multiple colours. in a traditional option one can use inline style but that style applies to the entire value not part of the value.

Comment: Are there any more ways to achieve this.@dvenkatsagar has provided a good example. However we have 2 other select options on the same page which look different to the style @dvenkatsagar has provided.Wish it was allowed in the option tag like this     <option><font color="red">red</font> <font color="blue">blue</font></option>

Comment: Well, a suggest would be to keep the selects a simple unified format/style, other wise you would need to modify code little for each select option. :)

Comment: Thanks @dvenkatsagar. We noticed that the colours do not appear when the browser mode is set to IE10 Internet Explorer 10 Compatibility view.
This is what our PC's default to.
To get the colours of jquery list to show we have to do this
In IE go to Tools --> F12 developer tools --> Go to Browsermode IE10 menu --> Select Interner Explorer 10